# i'm try django+ajax load the html,but them does't work

Tags: javascript, django

No solution has been found yet.
I actually want to load the page locally through ajax, I don't need to load it all

django code

```
#views.py
def test(request):
    if request.POST:
        a = request.POST['a']
        b = request.POST['b']
        data = a + b
        return HttpResponse(data)
    return render(request, 'test.html')
```

html code

```
<script src="https://apps.bdimg.com/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'js/csrf.js' %}"></script>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="a" id="a">
    <input type="text" name="b" id="b">
    <input type="submit" value="提交" id='go'>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#go").submit(function(){
        var a = $("#a").val()
        var b = $("#b").val()
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'test',
            data: {a: a, b:b, csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            success:function(res){
                alert(res);
            },
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

When I run, it jumps directly to 'request', and does not send via ajax.no pop-up alerts
sorry,I did not pay attention to some details, such as '.ajax' changed to '$ .ajax', the error has been modified through debugging

Your answer is important to me

Comment: use [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)  instead of HttpsResponse

Comment: thk, your reply has made the code run.but hasn't met expectations

Comment: I have answered. Do let me know if it solves your problem

Comment: thk,your answer can work.

Answer (score 1):

First you should call .submit() on form element.Second thing is you are calling an ajax function that runs asynchronously. It is possible that form gets submitted before your ajax function get the response.As ajax is asynchronous so it will not stop form being submitted.

I would advise you should do something like this:

```
<form method="POST" id="myForm">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="a" id="a">
  <input type="text" name="b" id="b">
  <input type="button" value="提交" id='go'>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#go").click(function(){
        var a = $("#a").val()
        var b = $("#b").val()
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'test',
            data: {"a": a, "b":b, "csrfmiddlewaretoken": '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            dataType:"json"
            success:function(response){
                alert(response.data);
                //if you want to submit form after this then
                $("#myForm").submit();
            },
         });

    });
});
```

views.py

```
def test(request):
    if request.POST:
        a = request.POST['a']
        b = request.POST['b']
        data = a + b
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"data":data}), content_type="application/json")
    return render(request, 'test.html')
```

You may find some answers which suggest to use **async:false** in ajax function but i must tell you that this has been deprecated and is know to cause bad user experience because it hangs the browser until response is fetched and ajax gets completed.

Comment: But i haven't tried async:false.i will try it later. thk

Comment: If my answer has helped you to solve your problem then you can accept it. Future audience will find it helpful. Regarding ajax:false , it will work even if you directly call form submit function but you will definitely experience a pause.

Comment: well, i understand ajax: return false , it prevent form submission.
so you do n’t have to jump to the web page when you visit,reach the effect of partial loading

Answer (score 0):

fisrt, thx for answering friend.

I made some changes, made changes to 'views', and adjusted 'ajax'. I think I will now use the combination of 'ajax' + 'django' to complete more functions.

## views.py

```
def test(request):
    if request.POST:
        a = request.POST['a']
        b = request.POST['b']
        data = a + b
        #return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
    return render(request, 'test.html')
```

## html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#go").click(function(){
        var a = $("#a").val()
        var b = $("#b").val()
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{% url 'test' %}",
            data: {"a": a, "b":b, "csrfmiddlewaretoken": '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(response){
                alert(response);                
            },
         });return false;
        
    });
});
```

it's run work.